# Unblur a specific zone with css

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I currently develop an ionic1 application and I would like to know if it's possible to "unblur" a specific floating `div` with the css rule 
`filter: blur(15px)`.

For my app, I need to have a view for show a secret pin code, and for secure the display, I would like to display the pin code in blur but when the user pass his finger on the screen, the part on where the user touch the screen need to be "unblur". The idea is to don't have the full code display in one times. (look at the picture)

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LDcw.png)

For this I try to set up two div:

- a div blur at 15px
- a `div` not blur

My question is, Is that the second `div` can "unblur" the first by superposition.

```css
.codePinView .blur {
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-filter: blur(15px);
  -moz-filter: blur(15px);
  -o-filter: blur(15px);
  -ms-filter: blur(15px);
  filter: blur(15px);
}

.codePinView .no-blur {
  position: fixed;
  height: 80px;
  width: 70px;
  top: 30vh; //only for superpose the two div
  left: 50vw; //only for supperpose the two div
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  -moz-filter: blur(0px);
  -o-filter: blur(0px);
  -ms-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
  z-index: 999999;
}
```

```html
<div class="pin blur">
  <div class="pin-block">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="no-blur">
</div>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this one?
First of all give spans a size, in order to keep a position grid for the mask we'll create.
Create a mask `.mask` and divide it in three parts: the middle one, will be the one which makes you see through the mask, give it a transparent background.
So the middle part will have the same size as the spans, while what cames before and after it will have a `calc((100 - spansize)/2)` a colored background and the blur on.
The mask is quite done, then i made it 200% of its parent width so when you'll move it, it will always stay on the pin.

Then just rely on JS to move its left from 0% to 100%, to make each number visible when you need it.

```css
.pin-block{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.pin-block span{
  width: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.mask{
  position: absolute;
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.mask .before-visible, .mask .after-visible{
  -webkit-filter: blur(15px);
  -moz-filter: blur(15px);
  -o-filter: blur(15px);
  -ms-filter: blur(15px);
  filter: blur(3px);
  width: calc((100% - 20px) / 2);
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
}

.mask .visible{
  float: left;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
}

.mask:after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="pin-block">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
    <div class="mask">
      <span class="before-visible"></span>
      <span class="visible"></span>
      <span class="after-visible"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply

The problem with this method is that I would like to have a floating div which follow my finger

Comment: @ArthurKnoep I modified my answer according to your request, this should work properly !